# Properties of sum of 2 normal random variables

Tags: statistics

just want to check if my solution is acceptable to the following question:

Suppose $Y_{1} \sim N(\mu_{1},\sigma_{1}^{2})$, $Y_{2} \sim N(\mu_{2},\sigma_{2}^{2})$ , and $Y_{1} \perp Y_{2}$. Show that $Y_{1} + Y_{2} \sim N(\mu_{1}+\mu_{2},\sigma_{1}^{2}+\sigma_{2}^{2})$

While I understand the approach of using MGFs and then showing that by the uniqueness property the above holds, is the below approach acceptable as well?

$E(Y_{1}+Y_{2}) = \mu_{1}+\mu_{2}$

$Var(Y_{1}+Y_{2}) = Var(Y_{1}) + Var(Y_{2}) - Cov(X,Y) = \sigma_{1}^{2}+\sigma_{2}^{2} - 0 = \sigma_{1}^{2}+\sigma_{2}^{2}$

(Cov(X,Y) = 0 because $Y_{1} \perp Y_{2}$)

Hence $Y_{1} + Y_{2} \sim N(\mu_{1}+\mu_{2},\sigma_{1}^{2}+\sigma_{2}^{2})$

Many thanks

Comment: That works as far as demonstrating what the mean and variance are, but it doesn't *necessarily* show that the resulting distribution will be normal

Comment: Thank you, so I suppose the MGF approach is needed here, since the uniqueness property will characterize the distribution, i.e. normally distributed

Comment: @SanjouOdawali : No, the mgf approach is certainly not the only way to do it. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thanks Michael, I suppose (trivally) using CGFs would work as well. For my understanding, what else did you have in mind?